# No module named 'pandas_schema'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When trying to `import pandas_schema`, I get the error *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_schema'*
I'm currently using PyCharm Community 2020.1.2

Details:
python 3.8.3
pip 20.1.1
pandas-schema 0.3.5
pandas 1.0.5
windows10 home 64-bit

Comment: Check your ENVs; Try pip install <module_name>

Comment: @Aditya I already installed the module 'pandas_schema' my problem is I think, pycharm can't detect the module. Though I'm not sure. I just started this today and started with sample codes.

Comment: Try to select the correct python version to run your cod then, like PyCharm  must be using with what it shipped, but you have installed it on another python on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your python environment. In a Powershell terminal, run

```bsh
PS /home/edgar> pip list | Select-String -Pattern pandas
pandas                             1.0.4
pandas-schema                      0.3.5
```

If `pandas-schema` is missing, then run

```bsh
PS /home/edgar> pip install pandas-schema
```

If the package is not missing then most likely your interpreter in PyCharm is not correctly setup. Run the following in PS:

```bsh
PS /home/edgar> Get-Command python
CommandType     Name      Version    Source
-----------     ----      -------    ------
Application     python    0.0.0.0    /path/to/python
```

Copy the `Source` value and go to `Settings > Project: myproject > Project Interpreter`, and next to the interpreter text field click the config icon and go to `Add...`. Paste the path to the Python interpreter as an existing environment.

Comment: I'm having an error when trying to use this command in powershell, 'pip list | grep pandas'  *grep : The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:12*

Comment: Though I tried 'pip list' then I got this:  Package         Version  
--------------- ---------  
certifi         2020.6.20  
chardet         3.0.4  
idna            2.9  
numpy           1.19.0  
pandas          1.0.5  
pandas-schema   0.3.5  
pip             20.1.1  
python-dateutil 2.8.1  
pytz            2020.1  
requests        2.24.0  
setuptools      41.2.0  
six             1.15.0  
urllib3         1.25.9  
wheel           0.34.2

Comment: Windows doesn't have grep

Comment: @ChristopherJohnReyes I changed the `grep` part. Seems like the package is installed in the environment in your terminal, but not in the one used by PyCharm, I updated the instructions.

Comment: @EdgarRamirezMondragon I don't know the exact problem but I've "fixed" my problem by deleting all the projects in my directory. I've also tried the pip list | Select-String -Pattern pandas (this was after deleting all the projects) and I can see the pandas-schema installed. I think the problem was in my PyCharm settings because I can't see the pandas-schema installed in the project interpreter earlier though I'm not sure why deleting all the projects in PyCharm fixed the problem.